# Activate HDMI output of nVidia GPU for audio without Windows extending the desktop to that display

Tags: audio, video, gpu, nvidia, hdmi

To get audio output from the HDMI port on an nVidia GPU the desktop must be extended to that output because the audio is contained within the video stream but if my monitor uses Displayport and the AV Reciever that is connected to the HDMI output does not support the resolution of my monitor I cannot use the portion of the desktop that is on the HDMI output.

Assuming that duplicating the desktop on the Displayport and HDMI outputs is not an option.

Is there a way to stop windows from extending the desktop to the secondary display, by invoking a system function for example, without deactivating the video output on the HDMI port or is the desktop tied into the graphics driver in such a way that this is not possible?

Comment: I put years of research and effort into this question, if no is the answer then just say no, a down vote with no comment is not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking into this as well... I am very surprised to learn that NVidia don't have a way of providing this.

I've found a few people recommending usine Dual Monitor Tools to lock your mouse to your Primary screen - not elegant, but is a solution I guess. :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).